# I can get response with postman but cannot get with axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I started a full stack app. I wrote models and routers on backend part. On frontend part, I installed axios and add "proxy": "http://localhost:xxxx/api" to package.json file. When I send get request with postman, it response me the data. But when I go to http://localhost:xxxx, on chrome console it says "AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST'"

Its my package.json file's last line;

```
}, "proxy": "http://localhost:8800/api"
}
```

Its my get router;

```
router.get("/", async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const pins = await Pin.find();
        res.status(200).json(pins);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err)
    }
});
```

and its my frontend app.js useEffect code:

```
useEffect( () => {
    const getPins = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get("/pins");
        setPins(res.data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    getPins();
  }, []);
```

Thanks for helps

Comment: Check developer tools > network tab for the request and if the URL is actually correct.

Comment: If you have an answer that differs from the accepted answer, add an answer. Do not add "(SOLVED)" to your title. Stack Overflow is not a forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of attempting to ping `axios.get("/pins")` try to ping `axios.get("/"`)`

I believe you are getting a 404 not found on the route as your frontend and backend routes don't match.

Comment: I'm developing a map website, when I go to main url (localhost:xxxx), there is react-map-gl map, so I inserted axios.get("/pins") useEffect. By the way you are right, I'm getting a 404 not found error

Answer (score 0):

I restarted Visual Studio Code and the problem solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).